# Get n points on a line

Tags: python, geospatial

If I have a line defined by a start and end coordinates, how do I get n equally spaced points on that line, taking the curvature of the earth into account?

I'm looking for an algorithm, and/or a python library that implements this.

Comment: I assume you need n equally spaced points along the geodesic joinig the two points?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What do the start and end coordinates look like?  Are they geographic latitude and longitude?  And there is an infinite number of paths you could take.  Are you restricting yourself to a path along a great circle?

Comment: Are they geographic latitude and longitude? - Yes, e.g.(28.22345, -26.14888) - (28.22357, -26.14943).

Comment: Are you restricting yourself to a path along a great circle? - Again, I think so. I'm busy reading to try understand the difference between a great circle and a geodesic.

Comment: Ok - I have now understood the difference between a great circle and a geodesic. For my purposes, a great circle will give me a sufficiently accurate approximate, and I suspect will be a simpler calculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [geographiclib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geographiclib), a python implementation of GeographicLib, I was able to do this:

```
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic

number_points = 10

gd = Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(35, 0, 35, 90)
line = Geodesic.WGS84.Line(gd['lat1'], gd['lon1'], gd['azi1'])

for i in range(number_points + 1):
    point = line.Position(gd['s12'] / number_points * i)
    print((point['lat2'], point['lon2']))
```

output:

```
(35.0, -7.40353472481637e-21)
(38.29044006500327, 7.8252809205988445)
(41.01134777655358, 16.322054184499173)
(43.056180665524245, 25.451710440063902)
(44.328942450747135, 35.08494460239694)
(44.76147256654079, 45.00000000000001)
(44.328942450747135, 54.91505539760305)
(43.05618066552424, 64.54828955993611)
(41.01134777655356, 73.67794581550085)
(38.290440065003274, 82.17471907940114)
(34.99999999999999, 90.0
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the npts method from pyproj's Geod class.
See 
https://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/pyproj.Geod-class.html

> Given a single initial point and terminus point (specified by python
>   floats lon1,lat1 and lon2,lat2), returns a list of longitude/latitude
>   pairs describing npts equally spaced intermediate points along the
>   geodesic *between* the initial and terminus points.

Emphasis mine because I missed that at first.

First you create an Geod instance, specifying the ellipsoid you want it to use. Then you can call the method.

```
from pyproj import Geod
geod = Geod("+ellps=WGS84")
points = geod.npts(lon1=-89.6627, 
                   lat1=39.7658, 
                   lon2=147.2800, 
                   lat2=-42.8500, 
                   npts=100
                  )
```

`points` is now a list of tuples on the geodesic line between your start and end point:

```
[(-91.27649937899028, 39.21278457275204),
 (-92.86468478264302, 38.6377120347621),
 (-94.42723159402209, 38.04136774269571),
 (-95.96421169120758, 37.42453136174509),
 (-97.47578514283185, 36.78797425216882),
...
```