# Connect two points on the surface of a sphere

Tags: python, connect, points

I need to connect two points that lay on a sphere, in that way, that the line (edge) stays on the surface of the sphere and doesn't go through it.

For now I have:

1. This sphere: [Evenly distributing n points on a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere)
2. The edges are plotted, but they go through the sphere.

   [image]
3. Desired result:

   [image]

Comment: Use Polar coordinates, find the two angles that describe the two points, linearly interpolate between the two values, interpolate using little straight segments.

Comment: are you looking for the geodesic line (or great circle arc)? maybe this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27605242/8069403) is helpful

Comment: You need to look up the many geographical packages available.  You'll need to work in spherical coordinates (polar is the 2D reduction), but the translation equations are included.

Comment: As a curiosity, what you're looking for has a name: **geodesic**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation of the [spherical linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) or slerp proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27615840/8069403):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def slerp(p1, p2, t):
    omega = np.arccos( p1.dot(p2) )
    sin_omega = np.sin(omega)    
    t = t[:, np.newaxis]
    return ( np.sin( (1-t)*omega )*p1 + np.sin( t*omega )*p2 )/sin_omega

p1 = np.array([1, 0, 0])
p2 = np.array([0, 1, 0])
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 30)

arc = slerp(p1, p2, t)

plt.plot( arc[:, 0], arc[:, 1] );
plt.axis('square');
```

which gives in 2D:

[image: 2D example]

Comment: @tory If an answer _"really helps!"_ it is customary for the OP to upvote and/or accept it.